# What governs the List element type of a scalar JPA native query?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

JPA provides the ability to run a native SQL query:

```
final Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT hork FROM foobar");
assert q != null;
final List results = q.getResultList();
```

In the query above, what kind of object will be present in my `List`?

Seems simple, but:

In our case, we have an Informix `TEXT` column.  The [Informix `TEXT` type](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/topic/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1413.htm) is kind of like a `CLOB`.

The Informix JDBC driver reports—and whether this is true or not we can't change it—that the [`java.sql.Types` field value to which this column is mapped](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnType%28int%29) is `java.sql.Types#LONGVARCHAR`.  OK.

If you run a regular old JDBC query like this:

```
final ResultSet rs = someStatement.executeQuery("SELECT hork FROM foobar");
assert rs != null;
while (rs.next()) {
    final Object result = rs.getObject(1);
    // see if you can guess what result.getClass() is
}
```

...you are working with `byte[]`, not `String`.

Now, if you run that native query above with the Big Two JPA providers (Hibernate, EclipseLink) you will get different objects in your result list.

Hibernate returns a `String` that is simply the contents of the column in `String` form, presumably via either `ResultSet#getString(int)` (instead of `ResultSet#getObject(int)`) or via some platform encoding of the resulting `byte[]`.

EclipseLink returns a hex representation of a `byte[]`, that, when decoded and interpreted in the ASCII character set, is, indeed, the contents of the column.

I have two related questions:

1. How do I instruct JPA what the type of a scalar native SQL query
   should be?
2. If EclipseLink doesn't return me a `String` representing the contents of the column, how come it doesn't just return me a `byte[]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very odd that your Informix JDBC driver is returning a TEXT value as a byte[], this seems very wrong, as it is a character field not a binary field, it should be a String.  You may wish to see if your JDBC driver has a fix for this.

JPA seems to be getting the value as a String because the JDBC meta-data says it is a String.

For EclipseLink what is really going on is that LONGVARCHAR is interpreted as a Clob type, and since a Clob can just be a locator the entire value must be fetched, so it converts the expected Clob to a String, but since it is actually a byte[], it gets converter to HEX.  You could fix this in your InformixPlatofrm by overriding isClob and returning false for LONGVARCHAR, but the real issue is that the JDBC driver is returning a byte[] for a character field.

Comment: Thanks, @James.  Can you think of any reason--on a related subject--why a field annotated like this: `@Lob private String hork;` would also get hex when populated via an `EntityManager.find()` call?  A colleague reports that this happens from time to time (!). I can't see any way at all that she could possibly be correct.

Comment: OK, here's my working theory: new entity with a `@Lob String` field is created, gets into the persistence context.  Gets `flush()`ed.  But obviously the entity is still in the persistence context. User sees "normal" strings, and will do so as long as the entity is found in either the persistence context or the level 2 cache.  Once it gets `refresh()`ed, due to the issues above the user will see hex.  Could be perceived as "random".

Comment: My theory was correct.  There was no `InformixPlatform#isClob()` method, but there is a `getObjectFromResultSet` method, which I overrode to use `getString(int)` in this scenario.